# DB2 interpret poorly formatted date

Tags: sql, db2

I have a tool which is populating a merge field I am using as part of generated SQL. The format is 113 (04 Aug 2020) and I cannot change it. What is the best way to make DB2 interpret this as a date?

Comment: I'm afraid, that nobody can tell you how to convert `int(113) -> date('2020-08-04')`. It's some application specific way of storing dates, and namely you should describe the logic of such a conversion.

Comment: For those wondering - `113` is the **SQL Server Format Identifier**.  Which is where many people's confusion is coming from (including mine).  OP has a normal date format problem, the number is a red herring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your date is in the format DD MON YYYY (I don't know what "113" is supposed to mean), then you can use `to_date()`:

```
to_date(merge_field, 'DD MON YYYY')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f978d7d1343e13d031eb270320d63a90) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . The OP would appear to disagree with you.  I also thought the question was pretty clear.

Comment: Argh - `113` is from SQL Server (see comment on question).